# Semantic and Unsemantic markup with re-useable CSS class names

Tags: html, css, class, semantics

I just want to ask a question as to whether my current method of creating class names is a terrible idea. Let me explain a little.

I am a web designer / application developer who loves PHP and can quickly create fully functioning, advanced PHP web applications that are responsive and look great. I like to create an inital template and then design my App in the browser; as and when a new page / html structure is written to the page in PHP.

**How I make my pages look GREAT!**

To generate PERFECT vertical rythym I user [drewish](http://drewish.com/tools/vertical-rhythm/) vertical rythym claculator which generators perfect spacing between paragraphs and headings. I then create the following classes:

```
.noTop {
    margin-top:0px;
}

.lgTop {
    margin-top: ( WHATEVER MY <h1> margin top is )
}    

.mdTop {
    margin-top: ( WHATEVER MY <h2> margin top is )
}

etc...
```

I now have EVERY class I need to sculpt a perfect vertical rythym website simply by spitting out HTML and adding classes to elements that look out of place. This really does work for me and ensures that EVERYTHING will always match up whilst only using a few class names. Also when another developer with an un-tranied design eye works on the project, I can rest assure that he will create spacing.

My question is, is this REALLY a terrible way of doing things for Vertical Rythym? An example case would be below:

```
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<h3 class="noTop">This is a perfectly sized & spaced sub line</h3>
<p>Example Text</p>

<img class="mdTop"  //Image that site perfectly under paragraph.
```

Thank you all in advanced. This method works for me but I know it isn't the best. Using this I can very quickly create prototypes. Is there a BIG reason why I shouldn't do this?

Comment: Semantic whise this is prefecture viable afaik. This is exactly what makes css powerfull. I use classes like this a lot, for me this looks very clean and clear. As for prototyping anything goes as long as it is fast.

Comment: It is good to hear someone agrees, I thought I may of got some abuse from this post!

Comment: Just wondering. What are other functions for classes?,everyone uses classes like that more or less re-usable.

Comment: Yes, but it was to my understanding after doing some research that the general rule is to make a class for each element that describes its function. So my example above would be more like:

    
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<h3 class="main-article-headline">This is a perfectly sized & spaced sub line</h3>
<p>Example Text</p>
<img class="article-figure"